# Complex switch statement

Tags: python, switch-statement

For example, I have:

```
def run():
  x = input()
  switch (x):
    case 1:
      print "case 1"
    case 2:
      print "case 2"
      break;
    case 3:
      print "3"
    case (4,5):
      print "4"
      print "5"
      break;
    default:
      print "default"
```

It is just pseudocode on Python. I tried to rewrite this program using real Python syntax:

```
def run():
  x = input()
  if x == 1:
    print ("case 1")
  if x == 1 or x == 2:
    print ("case 2")
  else:
    if x == 3:
      print ("3")
    if x == 3 or x == 4 or x == 5:
      print ("4")
      print ("5")
    else:
      print ("default")
```

Looks very ugly. Can I do this in another way; for example, using dictionaries?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use elif function

```
if x == 1:
    print ("case 1")
elif x == 1 or x == 2:
    print ("case 2")
elif x == 3:
  print ("3")
elif x == 4 or x == 5:
  print ("4")
  print ("5")
else:
  print ("default")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elif` instead of writing

```
else: 
    if x == 3:
```

And in Python, `if - elif` is used as `switch-case` like below in the rewritten code of yours.

```
def run(): 
    x = input() 
if x == 1: 
    print ("case 1") 
elif x == 2: 
    print ("case 2") 
elif x == 3: 
    print ("3") 
elif x == 4 or x == 5: 
    print ("4") 
    print ("5") 
else: 
    print ("default")
```

And for dictionary use please check this link: [Replacements for switch statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)